# Marklogic 8 http-get to AWS API gateway results in SSL handshake failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, marklogic, aws-api-gateway, tls1.2

I want to write a xquery module that calls an AWS API gateway endpoint. I ran code like the following:

```
xdmp:http-get("https://gxkhphr091.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod",
        <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
          <allow-sslv3>false</allow-sslv3>
          <allow-tls>true</allow-tls>
        </options>)
```

and all I get back is:

```
[1.0-ml] SVC-SOCCONN: xdmp:http-get("https://gxkhphr091.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod", <options xmlns="xdmp:http"/>)
-- Socket connect error: SSL_connect 192.168.15.17:59789-52.85.63.117:443: sslv3 alert handshake failure (0x14077410)
```

The endpoint doesn't require client certification. Doing a CURL from the same host works just fine:

```
curl -v https://gxkhphr091.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod
```

I read that AWS API Gateway doesn't support SSLv3 any more - it requires TLS, which is why I used the above options, but I also tried other combinations of options and they all result in the same SSLv3 error above.

I have tried with other https:// URLs such as those for AWS S3 and they work, so it's something different with the way API Gateway does SSL/TLS.

Any ideas what the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

From what I am finding elsewhere, it could be related to a lack of SNI support in the client. API Gateway requires HTTP clients that support SNI.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication